# AND OR query in elastic search

Tags: php, sql, elasticsearch

I need to dynamically make elastic search query based on AND, OR query.

User inputs a string similar to SQL format:

```
((("query1 query2" OR query3) OR query4) AND (query5 OR query6)) AND query7
```

I parse it to array:

```
[
    'AND' => [
        [
            'AND' => [
                [
                    'OR' => [
                        [
                            'OR' => [
                                '" query1 query 2"',
                                'query3'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'query4'
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'OR' => [
                        'query5',
                        'query6'
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ],
        'query7'
    ]

]
```

And based on this array I need to make a search for one field.

Something like:

```
{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"title":"research"}},{"match":{"title":"lecturer"}}]}}
```

But I'm stuck with nested conditions. Please advise.

Comment: Your query can be simplified to this `("query1 query2" OR query3 OR query4) AND (query5 OR query6) AND query7`. Then a simple `bool/must` wrapping two `bool/should` and one `match` would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small library out of it 
[SqlElasticSearchQueryConverter](https://github.com/santik/SqlElasticSearchQueryConverter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `bool` for nested conditions.

```
((("query1 query 2" OR query3) OR query4) AND (query5 OR query6)) AND query7
```

can be expressed as:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool":{
            "must" : [
                {           
                    "bool":{    // ((("query1 query 2" OR query3) OR query4) AND (query5 OR query6)) 
                        "must" : [  
                            {
                                "bool":{    // (("query1 query 2" OR query3) OR query4)
                                    "should" : [                                    
                                        {
                                            "bool":{    // ("query1 query 2" OR query3)
                                                "should" : [
                                                    {"match": // query1 query2},
                                                    {"match": // query3}
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {"match": // query4}
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool":{    // (query5 OR query6)
                                    "should" : [
                                        {"match": // query5},
                                        {"match": // query6}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {match":    //...  query7}
            ]
        }   
    }
}
```